# Bootstrap dropdown - value makes the width too big

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I have two dropdowns next to each other, something like this:

|Dropdown1|  |Dropdown2|

I have some values in dropdown1 that have lots of characters and I don't want them to disturb the width as soon as they are pressed. How can I do that ?

Here is my dropdown

```
 <div class="dropdown">
                        <div class="btn-group" id="storeId">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Tutorials
                                <span class="caret"></span></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML Tutorial</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS Tutorial</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">JavaScript Tutorial</a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4gjvne74/) the normal behaviour?

Comment: Yes, this is the normal behaviour

Comment: How about this? ---> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gjvne74/1/). This will set the `width` of "Tutorial" according the `width` of the `ul` element.

Comment: and where is your second dropdown in your code?